# rotating text in html

Tags: html

I am trying to design a piece of rotating text on a website and need help on where to start and how to accomplish this. I want it to say "Our Business Is ***_*** Your Business." and where the **_** is i want it to rotate with different words such as "growing" , "building" , "helping" ect. I can code html and am familiar with javascript and jquery. I dont want to do it with flash. At this point i have basic code written for mock up.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Rotating Text</title>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #00C;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p><strong>Our Business Is &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Your Business!</strong></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could accomplish this with jQuery easily, replace the area that you wish to replace with a span, and use jQuery to replace the contexts of that span with a random word from your array.

**HTML:**

```
<p><strong>Our Business Is <span id='test'>XXX</span> Your Business!</strong></p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Sets your words into an array
    var phrases =new Array("growing","building","helping");
    //Selects a random one
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length);
    //Sets your area to use that random word
    $("#test").text(phrases[random]);

});
</script>
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/B6pty/)

If you required a rotation, you could simply wrap that inside of a **[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval)** function:

**jQuery:**

```
function setRandomWord()
{
    var phrases =new Array("growing","building","helping");
    //Selects a random one
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length);
    //Sets your area to use that random word
    $("#test").text(phrases[random]);  
}

//Your function will fire every 5 seconds...
setInterval(setRandomWord,5000);
```

[**Working Demo with Interval**](http://jsfiddle.net/B6pty/3/)

**Full Code for Copy Pasting:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function setRandomWord(){
        var phrases =new Array("growing","building","helping");  
        $("#test").text(phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)]);
    }
    setInterval(setRandomWord,3000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<p><strong>Our Business Is <span id='test'>bettering</span> Your Business!</strong></p>    
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You....thats what i was thinking but my problem is though i can edit basic jQuery and javascript and understand its uses i cannot write it

Comment: Added a demo with an interval and without one :) Hope it helps you out.

Comment: its great and thank you so much....i have copied it but its not working for me in dreamweaver's preview `<html>
<head>
<title>Text</title>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function setRandomWord()
{
    var phrases =new Array("growing","building","helping");
    $("#test").text(phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)]);   
}

setInterval(setRandomWord,3000);
</script>

</head>

<body>

<p><strong>Our Business Is <span id='test'>bettering</span> Your Business!</strong></p>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: ahhh yes....i forgot about that...thank you so much it works great....im going to add some css and ill be good

Comment: Added the full copy-pasting section at the bottom of the post, it should be all that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval) [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/HBtfe/)

```
var words = ['Growing', 'building'];
var index = 0;

function rotate() {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Our Business Is " + words[(index++)%(words.length)] + " Your Business!!";
}

setInterval(rotate, 2000);
```

Comment: so are you saying something like this `<script>
var words = ['Growing', 'building'];
var index = 0;

function rotate() {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Our Business Is " + words[(index++)%(words.length)] + " Your Business!!";
}

setInterval(rotate, 2000);
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
 font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #00C;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p><strong>Our Business Is &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Your Business!</strong></p>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: Yes, but your `<p>` tag needs an ID like this `<p id="text"><strong>...`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array, populate it with the words you want, and then choose a random element of that array.

```
var words = new Array();
words[0] = "word 1";
words[1] = "word 2";
words[2] = "word 3";
words[3] = "words 4";

var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*4)

alert(words[randomnumber]);
```

where 4 dictates that the random number will fall between 0-3. To increase the range to, say, 100, simply change 4 to 101 instead